# What is the cause of all the problems in this class?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I was following an ASP.NET Core tutorial, writing my own code, when I ran into an unknown problem that's causing a lot of errors. I know that the guy in the tutorial is 
running ASP.NET Core 2.2.4, while I'm running ASP.NET Core 2.2.6.

The error is in a Controller. Here is the class:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

using Domain;
using Persistance;


namespace API.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
    {
        // With access to the Database Context, this controller can talk to the Database,
        // reading and updating values.
        private readonly DatabaseContext _DbContext;


        // CONSTRUCTOR INJECTION: Injecting the DatabaseContext service into the Values
        // class.
        public ValuesController(DatabaseContext dbContext)
        {
            this._DbContext = dbContext;
        }


        // GET api/values
        // This is made an Async method to push a task into a second thread: the act
        // of calling the database and retrieving the query results. By doing this, you
        // avoid blocking the main thread. 
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Value>>> Get()
        {
            // Retrieve a List of values from the 'Values' table. 
            var listOfValues = await _DbContext.Values.ToListAsync();
            // Return HTTP Status Code 200, along with the retrieved list of values. 
            return Ok(listOfValues);
        }

        // GET api/values/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Value>> Get(int id)
        {
            // There are several methods to help you get values from databases 
            // asynchronously: FindAsync(), FirstOrDefaultAsync(), SingleAsync(), and 
            // SingleOrDefaultAsync(). FindAsync() is used here because it is the most
            // appropriate - it will search the database by primary key and return the
            // value if found or 'null' if not. 
            var searchValue = await _DbContext.Values.FindAsync(id);
            return Ok(searchValue);
        }

        // POST api/values
        [HttpPost]
        public void Post([FromBody] string value)
        {
        }

        // PUT api/values/5
        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public void Put(int id, [FromBody] string value)
        {
        }

        // DELETE api/values/5
        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public void Delete(int id)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Most of it was generated from a template, and I started to change it according to the tutorial. There where no problems until I started to work on Get(int id). That's when Visual Studio Code started to give me errors all the time. As far as I can tell, I've done everything by the tutorial.

If there are two spaces between the Get() and Get(int id) methods, then latter method's heading gets several red underlines. Specifically, the keywords, "ActionResult", "Value", "Get", "int" all get underlined and as well as the last ">" and ")" in the method's heading.

The errors complain of:

> ```
> Syntax error, ','(CS1003)  
> Syntax error, '>'(CS1003)  
> Syntax error,> ','(CS1003)  
> Syntax error, ','(CS1003)  
> Syntax error, ','(CS1003) 
> Tuple must contain at least two elements. [...\Reactivities\API\API.csproj](CS8124)  
> Identifier expected [...\Reactivities\API\API.csproj](CS1001)  
> ) expected [...(CS1026)
> ```

If I so much as reduce the gap between Get() and Get(int id) methods from two to one line, all the red squiggly in the method heading vanish and instead only the opening brace in Get(int id) gets a red squiggly line.

These are the associated errors:

> ```
> Syntax error, ','(CS1003)  
> Syntax error, '>'(CS1003)  
> Identifier expected [...\Reactivities\API\API.csproj](CS1001)  
> Syntax error, ','(CS1003)  
> Syntax error, ','(CS1003)  
> Identifier expected [...\Reactivities\API\API.csproj](CS1001)  
> Syntax error, ','(CS1003)  
> Tuple must contain at least two elements. [...\Reactivities\API\API.csproj](CS8124)  
> Identifier expected [...\Reactivities\API\API.csproj](CS1001)  
> ) expected [...(CS1026)
> ```

I think this is some sort of syntax error, but I don't know what it might be. Does anyone feel like taking a look at this code, please?

Comment: Which line is the first line that it complains about? The declaration of `Get(int id)`? And what is the error it tells you about that line?

Comment: You've got a typo somewhere. I don't see any commas in your code, so I'm wondering if one of your code comments isn't properly marked (e.g. you accidentally used one `/` instead of two). I suggest you roll back to the template, make your changes in small steps, and compile in between steps, so you can determine which change introduced the issue. In general, it's better to make small changes and test iteratively-- compile early and compile often.

Comment: @Gabriel Luci: All the errors are on Line 47 at different characters.

Comment: What's line 47?

Comment: public async Task<ActionResult<Value>> Get(int id)

Comment: Basically, the Get(int id) method is where the problem started and where I get errors. I get 10 errors about that line, starting with a syntax error about about a comma. The rest are listed above.

Comment: Best thing I can suggest is comment out the line, and then type it out below. Type it out, don't copy/paste. Sometimes [weird characters can get in there are can't be seen](http://jkorpela.fi/chars/spaces.html). Although I don't see any of that when I copy/paste your code into my Visual Studio.

Comment: The code you posted looks fine and should at least compile. Close and open Visual Studio

Comment: I've already typed it out three or four times, that didn't help. I rebooted VS Code, and now the errors have migrated down to lines 49 and 50, which are both comments. Absolutely bizzare.

Comment: @DalyJohn Maybe the projects temporary files are busted? This can happen and there should be a "rebuild project" or "rebuild solution" operation. | Of course it might also be unprintable characters/fake whitespace characters.

Comment: Hmm... Maybe it is finding some `ambiguity` with the `Get(int id)`, and `Get()` -Though, I don't know why it would...

Comment: Could you send over the `source code`? I'll take a look it for you :) `Shreddedcoconu1@gmail.com`

Comment: I remember having similar problems after copy/pasting some code. It turned out that there were some invisible unicode characters in the code. Found it by looking at the source file with a binary editor.

Answer (score 0):

These kinds of errors mean this:

- there is a Syntax error somewhere
- the syntax error is so bad, the compiler can not even tell you *where* it is anymore. Indeed it is so bad, he will produce a dozen or so other errors, in a vain attempt to make sense of that input.

The real error will be the 1st line with a error report. Or before that. A common mistake is an extra/missing semikolon. Followed by extra/missing quotation marks. But even on closer inspecition, I can find no obvious issue with the code.

Comment: Yes, I tried looking for out of place commas or semi-colons, but I couldn't find any either. I tried typing out the code, rebooting VSCodium and everything else, I knew to try. But the problem seems to become more and more weird. I think a full computer reboot is required.

Comment: Thanks for your help, everyone. Much appreciated!

Comment: Nope, a reboot has not fixed the problem. Perhaps I have to rewrite this project or at least this class.

Answer (score -1):

I checked (copy/paste) and there is no syntax issue in this piece of code.

It may be an error in another file. It may be an issue with IntelliSense. I recommend a rebuild, maybe a restart.